# Setting background to 100% height and keep footer at the bottom of page

Tags: html, css

I know this question has been asked many times but none of the answers solved my situation.
Here is a the demo http://jsfiddle.net/eyuxt3zz/18/ for wich I need that the `#marketing_logo` div background image should extend to 100% and to be tangent to footer div.
If I set the #content div to 100% using `dispaly:absolute` then the footer will not keep his bottom position.
I tried some solution but I cannot figure it out how to keep the footer at the bottom of the page when another div is also set to `position: absolute`.

The height for the background is now set to 300 px so that the content div does not appear empty.

So the question is how to make `#marketing_logo` div background to size 100% and keep footer div at the bottom. The footer div is set to position absolute so that it always stays at the bottom of the page.

Thanks!

demo http://jsfiddle.net/eyuxt3zz/18/

html code

```
<body>
    <div id="page" class="pageContainer">   
        <div class="ppContainer">
            <div id="container">
                <div id="marketing_logo"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">Footer</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS code

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    margin: 0;
} 
.pageContainer {
  min-height: 100%;
}
#marketing_logo {
  background: url('http://www.canvaz.com/portrait/charcoal-1.jpg') no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height:300px
}
#footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #BBBBBB;
  text-align: left;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: The JsFiddle is a bit broken i think. You have a ׳#content׳ in your CSS, but no element with ׳id="content"׳ in your HTML

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#marketing_logo {
  background: url('http://www.canvaz.com/portrait/charcoal-1.jpg') no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0 -15px -150px -15px;
  width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;  
      position: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, i am not sure this is what you are looking for? [Example codepen](http://codepen.io/o0nico0o/pen/VLowoB)

```
body,html{
height:100%;
}

#wrapper{
min-height:100%;
height:auto !important;
height:100%;
margin:0 auto -150px; /* minus the height of the footer */
}

#marketing_logo{
background: url('http://www.canvaz.com/portrait/charcoal-1.jpg') no-repeat center center;
height:100vh;
width:100%;
background-size:100%;
}

#push, footer{
height:150px; /* height of the footer */
clear:both;
}

footer{
background:#BBBBBB;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this with JavaScript/jQuery. Here is your updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eyuxt3zz/19/).

The JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Calculate heigth
    function calcHeight() {
        var height = $(window).height() - $('#footer').height();
        $('#marketing_logo').css('height', height);
    }
    // Auto call calcHeight on page load
    calcHeight();

    // Call calcHeight when the browser window resizes
    $(window).resize(calcHeight);
});
```

I created a little function called `calcHeight`. I call this function on page load and when the user resizes the window. Inside this function, I calculate the height of the footer and the remaining height (height of the window - the height of the footer) to update the height of your `marketing_logo`.